# For a measure space prove if $f$ is measurable and bounded then there exists simple functions that converge to it?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measure space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and bounded. Then there exists a sequence of simple measurable functions $f_n$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, ie:
$$\forall\epsilon>0 \mbox{ } \exists N \mbox{ } s.t. \forall x \in X \mbox{ } \forall n\geq N, |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon $$

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I completely missed the word "uniformly" in your question.  I have to think about this a little more. I'm not sure my answer was completely right.

Comment: I'm on mobile right now, so I can't type out a full answer. I'll give a hint, though. Chop up the range of f into little bits, say, disjoint intervals $[a_i,b_i)$ of length $2^{-n}$. Then $f_n = \sum_i a_i \chi(f^{-1}([a_i, b_i)))$ should do what you want.

Comment: Hi could you explain a little more? Is it using the monotone convergence theorem?